# How can I recover a corrupted Zsh history file from memory?

Tags: zsh, command-history

For reasons that partially escape me (and are outside the scope of this question), my Zsh history file became corrupt.  I have several sessions open that have the history in memory.  Is there a way to recover the history *file* (in its correct format) from what's in memory?

While the output of the `history` or `fc` commands looks like this (by default, at least)

```
57694  type -a ssh-keygen
57695  ssh -v localhost
```

while the file is in a format like

```
: 1545938685:133;vim ~/.zshrc
: 1545938820:0;exit
```

(Obviously these are not the same entries—I just give them to display the format, and therefore the problem I'm facing.)

Is there any way to get `fc` to display all the data that I would need to recreate the history *file* as it was before it became corrupted?

(If this is not possible, I can recover *most* of it from a backup drive, of course, but I would rather recover all of it, and it would be useful to know how to do this in the future.)

Comment: @jimmij The corrupted file has already been deleted by `zsh`, so I can't recover by editing the history file.

Comment: @jimmij And since I have `57698` lines in memory, I'm pretty sure I _do_ have the entire history in memory, based on `fc -l 1 | wc -l`.  What you said maybe true by default, but apparently not with my current Zsh settings.

Comment: OK, so if you are sure have it all then `fc -W` should write and `fc -A` append history to the file. You can pass filename as an argument.

Comment: The only problem (which also occurs with `fc -i`—or any of the other date options) is that the dates are all wrong before a certain command.  I assume that's when the session began, and only commands were loaded into memory, but not dates of previous commands.

Comment: Does `fc -R ~/.zsh_history` help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Digging into `ZSHBUILTINS(1)`'s man page I found that:

```
fc -W .zsh_history_from_ram
```

writes to a file the history in the exact same format it is saved by `zsh` in `~/.zsh_history`.
This will work as long as you have a shell session that still has the history in memory.